# Generating Expression Tree for List.Any(v => v.Contains(Book.Title.ToString()))

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

As the title says, I'm trying to generate an Expression tree for cheking if any item in a list of strings matches a string of a Book object.

So far I've got this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, bool>> GenerateListContainsLikeExpression(string propertyName, List<string> values)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
        var listParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "v");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        var toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
        var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        var objectString = Expression.Call(property, toStringMethod);
        var lambda = Expression.Call(listParameter, containsMethod, objectString);
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<string>, bool>>(lambda, parameter);
        var comparison = Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.Constant(values), func);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean]' of method 'Boolean Any[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Func`2[System.String,System.Boolean])'

At this line:

```
var comparison = Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.Constant(values), lambda);
```

I feel like I just need the last little bit.

Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT: For clarification. I'll explain a little more detailed what I needed.

I needed to categorize books based on some of the books properties. In this specific case, I pass a list of strings to the function. I needed to check if any of these strings was contained in any books title.

So first of all, the lambda I thought I needed was wrong to begin with. This is the lambda that I actually needed: `b => values.Any(v => b.Title.ToString().Contains(v))`

And here is the final code I ended up with:

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, bool>> GenerateListContainsLikeExpression(string propertyName, List<string> values)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
        var listParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "v");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        var toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
        var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        var objectString = Expression.Call(property, toStringMethod);
        var lambda = Expression.Call(objectString, containsMethod, listParameter);
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(lambda, listParameter);
        var comparison = Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.Constant(values), func);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
    }
```

Comment: Your func is probably not what you think it is, and probably screwed up.  Any is an extension method, so you'd have to call the static method within your Expression.  Is List supposed to be a list of Books?  Looks like it is, but it appears you treat the argument for the Any func to be a list itself, not one of the books in the list.  Everything looks wrong... I think there's a lambda => expression converter you can use to learn how stuff works... lemme peek for it.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can just go `Expression<Func<TInput,bool>> expr = x => x.Any(v => v.Contains(Book.Title.ToString()));` and then examine the expression within the quick watch window to see how it's constructed.  Again, I don't know what your `TInput` is from the lambda in your title.

Comment: I've edited the post so you can see the full method.

Comment: The lambda is still incorrect.  You're wanting `b => values.Any(v => b.Any(x => x.Title.ToString().Contains(v)))`, where `values` would be a const enumerable of string values.  Your method is returning a func that takes `Books` as its argument.  Looking into it.

Comment: @Will The lambda is correct. I'm using the lambda in a Where() afterwards making the final result books.Where(b => values.Any(v => b.Title.ToString().Contains(v)))

Comment: No, your method returns an expression of type `Func<Books, bool>`.  That means, in your lambda, `b` is of type `Books`.  You're using it as if it was of type `Book`, which it is not.  Unless `Books` has a property `Title`, which doesn't make sense from this end.  That's one of the issues you're facing.

Comment: Yes, I'm using b as type Books, because it is. And the code is working so I'm not sure what you want to prove that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Let's zero in here... `b => values.Any(v => b.Title.ToString()` ... `b => b.Title`  ... Does the type `Books` contain a property called `Title?` It's confusing from this end, as a *book* has a title, and a collection of books don't always share a title.  Just trying to clarify...

Comment: If you resolved your own problem (it seems your final code is fine) - maybe you should post answer to your own question to not confuse other people.

Comment: @Evk I will post my final code as the answer, just wanted hear Will if I did something horribly wrong ;-)

Comment: @Will Yes, Books does indeed have a property called Title. And I just now realize why you're confused. Our database table is called Books, and therefore Entity Framework calls the model Books. I'm used to it by now and am therefore blind to the fact :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final working code:

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, bool>> GenerateListContainsLikeExpression(string propertyName, List<string> values)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
    var listParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "v");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
    var toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
    var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
    var objectString = Expression.Call(property, toStringMethod);
    var lambda = Expression.Call(objectString, containsMethod, listParameter);
    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(lambda, listParameter);
    var comparison = Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.Constant(values), func);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
}
```

For a more in depth explanation of the problem. See my edit in the original post.